# Add tag words from .get in tagging object

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, tags, tagging

I bring the concept of keywords to my page with tags. The page serves as an "Add" and "Edit" page. I will look for my information by a $ .get when it is that of "Modify". My problem is that it works 1 out of 2 times on the page load.

Here's when it works:
[image]

and here's when it doesn't. Here is my code:
[image]

This is how I build my object tagging:

I don't know the tagging object in depth, so maybe this is not the way to insert tags.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".tag").tagging({
                'no-spacebar': true, // default - false
                'forbidden-chars': [".", "_", "?", "#", "×", "  "], // double space added
                "forbidden-chars-callback": function () {
                    sweetAlertInput("Vous ne pouvez utiliser ce caractère ", "etabMotsClef");
                },
                'no-duplicate-callback': function () {
                    sweetAlertInput("Vous avez déjà utilisé ce mot clé ", "etabMotsClef");
                },
                'no-duplicate': true,
                'no-enter': false,
                'tags-limit': 5,
                'no-del': true,
                'no-quote': true,
                'edit-on-delete': false,
                'no-comma': true,
                'type-zone-class': true,
                'no-focus': true,
                "tag-on-blur": 0
            });

        });
```

The get:

```
   $.get("@Html.Raw(Url.Action("TelechargerInfoOrganisme", "Etablissements"))", function (data) {
        //$("#dropdownCFsection").html('<div class="row"><div class= "col-md-6"><div class="form-group"><label for="projectinput5"><strong>@Resource.Organisme</strong></label><select id="organisme" name="organisme" class="custom-select"></select></div></div>');
        $.each(data, function (index, row) {
        
            if (row?.etab_motcle) {
                var motsString = row?.etab_motcle;
                //console.log(motsString);
                var motsArray = motsString.split(',');
                //console.log(motsArray);
                $.each(motsArray, function (index, value) {
                    $('#etabMotsClef').append(value + ', ');
                });
            }
        });
     });
```

And the html:

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label><strong>Liste des mots clés:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-info add-special-keys" style="padding-top:3px;padding-bottom:3px;padding-right:6px;padding-left:6px;" type="button"><i class="feather icon-plus"></i></button></label>
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-6">
                 <div class="tag form-control" style="height:120px;outline: none;" data-tags-input-name="tag" maxlength="250" id="etabMotsClef" name="etabMotsClef"></div>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I use this github to guide me:
https://github.com/sniperwolf/taggingJS#available-options

Answer (score 0):

I found a new approach in the object tagging instead of making an append in my div t works and I no longer have the problem:

```
var motsArray = [];

     $(document).ready(function () {

            $.get("@Html.Raw(Url.Action("TelechargerInfoOrganisme", "Etablissements"))", function (data) {
                //$("#dropdownCFsection").html('<div class="row"><div class= "col-md-6"><div class="form-group"><label for="projectinput5"><strong>@Resource.Organisme</strong></label><select id="organisme" name="organisme" class="custom-select"></select></div></div>');
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                   
                    if (row?.etab_motcle) {
                        var motsString = row?.etab_motcle;
                        //console.log(motsString);
                        motsArray = motsString.split(',');
                        console.log(motsArray);
//////HERE THAT I ADD MY KEYWORDS IN MY TAGS
                        $('.tag').tagging("add", motsArray);
                    }

                });
            });

            $(".tag").tagging({
                'no-spacebar': true, // default - false
                'forbidden-chars': [".", "_", "?", "#", "×", "  "], // double space added
                "forbidden-chars-callback": function () {
                    sweetAlertInput("Vous ne pouvez utiliser ce caractère ", "etabMotsClef");
                },
                'no-duplicate-callback': function () {
                    sweetAlertInput("Vous avez déjà utilisé ce mot clé ", "etabMotsClef");
                },
                'no-duplicate': true,
                'no-enter': false,
                'tags-limit': 5,
                'no-del': true,
                'no-quote': true,
                'edit-on-delete': false,
                'no-comma': true,
                'type-zone-class': true,
                'no-focus': true,
                "tag-on-blur": 0
            });

        });
```